# Как поменять телефоны в зависимости от страны?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Можно ли поменять телефоны на сайте в зависимости от страны (Если пользователь киргиз, чтобы он видел киргизские номера, если пользователь россиянин, то российские и т.д.)? Наведите на мысль, в какую сторону копать. Спасибо.

Comment: Копать в сторону IP-адреса пользователя и GeoIP. Или смотреть на язык браузера. Что больше нравится.

Answer (score 3):

Как правило, страну из которой пришёл посетитель определяют по его IP. Далее выводят информацию, которая предназначена для посетителей из данной конкретной страны.Также можно проверять используемый язык браузера.

Однако необходимо учитывать, что ни тот ни другой подходы, не дают 100% достоверности. Пользователь может использовать прокси сервер или переехать вместе со своим компьютером/ноутбуком/планшетом/смартфоном в другую страну.